# Fullcalendar editable property not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, fullcalendar

Here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        dayClick: function() {
            alert('nemke');
        },        
        events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'UserCalendarService.asmx/GetEvents',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'xml',
                data: {start: + Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),end: + Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)},                
                success: function(result) {                
                var events = [];
                $(result).find('Event').each(function() {
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).find('Title').text(),
                        start: $(this).find('Start').text(),
                        editable: $(this).find('Editable').text() 
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
                }
            });
        },
        disableResizing: true,
        editable: false
        //disableDragging:true
    })  
});
```

This property editable false is not working. I tried to set each event it's behavior from the server, and it didn't work. Then I tried to set the property to false, and it also didn't work. I need to set some events editable and some not. I can only set disableDragging, but that doesn't solve my issue 'cause I need some of the events to be able to drag.

This property only works with event source set as array like this [example](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.1/demos/basic-views.html) 
Looks like this ajax callback is not working. Has anyone had similar issue?

[Fullcalendar link](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in code, I changed URL to json feed and now it works, but still this is an open issue remaining

Comment: Have you found this solution?

Answer (score 6):

the .text() method returns a string and `editable` is supposed to have a boolean value